# How to get previous iTerm2 command by typing partial command and pressing "up"

Tags: terminal, iterm2

In my terminal, when I type a partial command like "git clone" and then press "up", it will scroll through each previous command with that beginning of "git clone". When I try this in iTerm2 it just scrolls back the the immediate, previous command.

How can you mimic this behaviour in iTerm2?

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally hit a solution. I've had this problem for a while on my new computer but the interesting thing is that on my old one this feature works perfectly fine!

One way to tackle this problem is a command. " r". Control-r is used in just this scenario. Press  r and you got the solution you need.

The way to experience your terminal before is by a zsh extension. If zsh is already your defaulted shell your good. Install zsh-atuosuggestions and that will be exactly the thing your looking for. I even believe you can delete the grayed out suggestion to make it feel even more "your" terminal. If you don't have zsh installed its fine. If you use fish or something else there's probably a extension for that too. If your a little puzzled of what a shell is or doesn't know any options I recommend zsh. It's quite simple and easy and there are plenty of good tutorials of how to get it installed and how to install extensions with it. To install zsh-autosuggestions see the refered link at the bottom of the answer.

I've heard fish has some of these suggestions built in so if the above don't work out for you it is a option to try. But if your a little uncomfortable with different shells I don't recommend this option. To install fish, see the refered link at the bottom of the file.

Hope some of these suggestions helped!

zsh-autosuggestions: "https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions"
fish-shell: "https://fishshell.com/"